# Could the Menorah be Cast in a mold?

Tags: art, parashat-teruma

In the description of the menorah in Sh'mot 25:[31](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9886#showrashi=true), there is a requirement that the menorah be hammered ("The menorah shall be made of hammered work;") and Rashi explains that it is to be hammered out of a single ingot, "it must not be made in sections, [which can be removed]. Its branches and its lamps should not be made individually and then attached, as is the custom of the smiths [through a process] called solderez [in French], soldering, but it [the menorah] must come [be constructed] entirely from one piece [of gold]-beaten with a hammer and cut with a tool, and the branches separated on both sides".

This is an [arduous](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UZOTJh8gqY) and [difficult](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGElSHzm0q8) process. A simpler process might be the construction of a mold, with the molten gold [poured](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xuFO6a5wIQ) into it to make, out of a single pouring, the entire of the menorah, fully formed. Would this satisfy the requirements of the pasuk?

Initially, my concern was that there might be no hammering involved and that the pasuk was precise in its demand, but then I read that according to Rashi, "Since Moses found difficulty with it [i.e., figuring out how to form the menorah], the Holy One, blessed is He, said to him, “Cast the talent [equivalent to sixty-four pounds of gold] into the fire, and it will be made by itself.” " Apparently, the actual menorah which was used in the mishkan was not hammered. So would one made in the future have to be hammered if it could be poured instead?

Comment: Couldn't you hammer a bit after casting a conveniently close starting point to fulfill hammering?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know -- the text only mentions hammering (and Rashi adds in "cut with a tool"). But if the original could have been cast, then I'm not sure why Moshe would have had such difficulty "figuring out how to form the menorah".

Comment: I wonder what the Temple Institute has to say about this.

Comment: I am sure there is a much deeper reason as to why Moshe had "difficulty" figuring out how to form the Menorah, and that it should not suggest that the Menorah should be formed in a fire by default.

Answer (score 4):

Rav Yosef Bechor Shor to [25:31](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/25.31#e0n7) states clearly that the word "Miksha" comes to exclude the possibility of using a mold, what is referred to by the Torah as "Yetzikah" (see, for example, Shemos [25:12](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/25.12#e0n7)).  Based on similar-sounding interpretations by other Rishonim there, I would assume that this is accepted.